# Create hyperlink formula field which when clicked should redirect to specified record page

Tags: formula

There are 2 custom objects linked to each other via lookup. The requirement is to create a hyperlink formula field in the child record which when clicked should direct to parent record page.Is this requirement possible via hyperlink formula field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a Text formula field with something like  ...

```
HYPERLINK(
  "/" & Your_LookUp_On_Child__c, 
  "whatever text you want",
  "_self"
)

/* or if you want the record name */

HYPERLINK(
  "/" & Your_LookUp_On_Child__c,
  Your_LookUp_On_Child__r.Name,
  "_self"
)
```

Note 1: Change `_self` to `_blank` if you need the link to open in a new page

Note 2: For standard relationship fields, replace

- the `__c` of `Your_LookUp_On_Child__c` by `Id`
- the `__r` of `Your_LookUp_On_Child__r` by nothing

Note 3: If it can be empty, use a conditional clause (`IF`) to show the HYPERLINK if `Your_LookUp_On_Child__c` is not empty

Comment: What would be the return type of formula field in this case?

Comment: @Return0 Just Text should be ok

Comment: Then i am getting  error as Error: Field $Action.Car__c.View does not exist. Check spelling.

Comment: Car_Type__c is the field API name of lookup to parent and Car__c is the API name of child object

Comment: @Return0 updated the formulas ;)

Comment: @Return0 With what I read, your case would be `IF(ISBLANK(Car_Type__c),"",HYPERLINK(
  "/" & Car_Type__c, 
  "Click here",
  "_self"
))`

Comment: Can we fetch a text field value from parent object and put in place of "Click here"in this formula?

Comment: Tried it out...yes we can ;)