# Connecting a Contact to another Contact

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, formula-field

I have "student" contacts and I have "parent" contacts which are connected by a relationship which can be viewed in related lists. But I want to link the parent contact record to the student contact record in a field.

I tried a lookup field but it only returns relationship IDs, not names which makes it hard to find the right one. I'd also really love for it to be somewhat automated.

Ideal situation:

1. Student fills out sign up form in which they give parent information
2. Student and Parent contacts are both created in Salesforce from form (this is already set up)
3. "Parent Contact" field autofills with link to parent contact

I feel like there has to be a way to do this with a formula maybe? Or a flow? I'm still pretty new to this and haven't been able to find a solid answer yet.

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the contact record where I want to add the parent name:

[image]

The problem I'm having with a lookup field is that it returns "RN-000192" instead of the parent's name.

Comment: Lookup is the right idea. It's unclear where do you want the Parent Name to show up - a screenshot would be helpful (please edit your question).

Comment: You want to show the details of a related record in a separate panel by modifying the page layout. Take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbJk2aJvdrA

Comment: "You want to show the details of a related record in a separate panel by modifying the page layout. Take a look at this video: youtube.com/watch?v=xbJk2aJvdrA"

This is how it's currently setup and it doesn't work for us to have it as a related record in a separate panel. I need it to be a field.

Comment: Try a formula field with HYPERLINK(): https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305040/create-hyperlink-formula-field-which-when-clicked-should-redirect-to-specified-r

Comment: The lookup field will always show the Name field on the UI which I am guessing is an auto number in your case. You can add more field using formula or as related record as mentioned by other above. You can change the Name field from auto number and populate it automatically on save if required.